# gatsby-source-wordpress wpgraphql allWpCategory count not updating when I start assigning post

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, wp-graphql, gatsby-cloud

I hope everyone see this and have the same issue.

I'm using headless approach with gatsbyjs, my problem is the count, IT'S not updating when I start assigning post in the categories. It's still showing null, even though there is a post in the category. I understand, running yarn clean will fix everything, but shouldn't be automatically updating the graphql as will as in the gatsby cloud?

```
  allWpCategory(filter: {slug: {eq: "boxing"}}) {
    nodes {
      name
      count
    }
  }
```

I'm expecting to see value in the category count without clearing cache.

Comment: By default, the count is not updated automatically when you assign or remove posts from a category. Using gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental instead provides some futures to automaticaly update the schema. Or run command to clear the cache ?